# Integrate packages into Ubuntu install

Tags: ubuntu, packages

Is it possible to integrate the newest packages into an ubuntu install.

Comment: Can you be more specific.  Do you simply want to update packages?  Do you want to remaster the install cd.  Do you want to install newer versions of software then what is the repository?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. What do you want to achieve? What did you try? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear, so I have two answers, depending on what you are really asking.

To update an Internet-connected Ubuntu system with the latest packages: go to the System menu (top left of your desktop) and choose Administration/Update Manager.  Click on "Install Updates".  Alternatively (command-line option): open a terminal emulator and run:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

To get an Ubuntu install CD with the newest packages: get a "daily build" install CD from here:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily/current/

You can use this install CD to update the packages on a system that isn't connected to the Internet.

EDIT: Note that a "daily build" CD will have the very latest packages.  If you want, say, an Ubuntu 9.04 install CD with the latest Ubuntu 9.04 packages, I'm not sure where you would go.  The usual thing is to simply install 9.04 and then let the system update itself as I explained in the first part of the answer.

EDIT: Okay, did another Google search and found how to make a custom Ubuntu install CD.  You can easily fold in the latest packages for a stable Ubuntu, or fold in your own special-purpose packages.  Here's the URL:  http://maketecheasier.com/reconstructor-creating-your-own-ubuntu-distribution/2008/07/05

And here is a direct link to the tool you use: [Reconstructor](http://www.reconstructor.org/wiki/reconstructor/)

The Google search terms I used were "make your own Ubuntu distro".

EDIT: I also found another tool: [UCK - Ubuntu Customization Kit](http://uck.sourceforge.net/)